# Laravel pointing subfolder into other name

Tags: wordpress, laravel, blogs, subdirectory

I have a laravel project that include multiple domain inside.
I want to make the blog for each domain using wordpress. I already install the wordpress succesfully, but since this laravel project is a multiple domain inside, I install the wordpress project for each domain using "domainname_blog" on the public folder.

```
public_html
|- public
  |- aa_blog
  |- bb_blog
  |- cc_blog
```

What I want to ask is, is it possible to access the blog using aa.com/blog instead of aa.com/aa_blog?
I hope I can access aa.com/blog that pointing to aa_blog without any redirecting, because now I only can access it using aa.com/aa_blog. I tried a lot of changing htaccess method but still not working.

Please for your advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to segregate the Blog Folder from your laravel .htaccess file. Please write the code into your .htaccess file [ laravel ]. Hope it will solve your issue.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)
```

.htaccess file will look like :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```